# Sum of a series $\frac{1}{x} \theta^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I compute the sum of this series: $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \theta^x$?

Edit: There was a typo in the original question.  The sum is not infinite and ends in $m$.  Is there an analytical solution to series:

$Y = \sum_{x=1}^{m} \frac{1}{x} \theta^x$

By taking the derivatives and summing, I found $\frac{dY}{d\theta} = \frac{1-\theta^m}{1-\theta}$.  How do I integrate from here?

Comment: Looks like the power series for log to me

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know where to start.  But I think Stephen's comment helps.

Comment: The derivative of this series with respect to $\theta$ is a geometric series. Find its sum. Then antidifferentiate with respect to $\theta.$ Then think about what the constant of integration must be.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  To the person that downvoted the question, I didn't see that I can take derivatives.  I actually tried integration by parts and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$. Then $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}$.

So $$xf'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}-1=\frac{x}{1-x}$$
whenever $|x|<1$

Hence $f(x)=\int \frac{1}{1-x} dx=-\log(1-x)$

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If the sum is to m, not $\infty$, this approach doesn't work.